# How can I configure my python package to copy files to a subfolder of scripts post installation

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, python-wheel

I have a python package that comes with a variety of scripts in other languages. Setuptools already supports copying these scripts into the `scripts` directory of the environment to make them accessible from the command line. For this purpose I can simply use the following keyword in the setup commmand:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts=["bin/script1.bat", "bin/script2.bat"],
    ...
    )
```

After installing the package, the script files will end up correctly in the `scripts` folder of the environment.

**My question:**
Is there a way to have these files end up in a subfolder of the `scripts` directory? Something like `scripts/odd_scripts/script1.bat` and `scripts/even_scripts/script2.bat`.

Comment: The problem is that, unlike the top scripts directory, subdirs like `odd_scripts` and `even_scripts` (or whatever subdir names the package decided) would not normally be on $PATH, so the scripts would not be runnable except by absolute path.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. In my scenario the calling program would be aware of the absolute path and not use $PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are not Python scripts, you don't need the main feature of `scripts` (which is: rewriting the shebang to point to the same executable as the Python runtime which was used to install the package).

In this case, you can just package them as [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files), the original executable bits and shebangs will be preserved:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    data_files=[('bin/odd_scripts', ['bin/script1.bat']),
                ('bin/even_scripts', ['bin/script2.bat'])],
    ...
)
```

Comment: Amazing. Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to remove this as accepted answer. I just realized, that the data_files method is deprecated and won't work with wheels. (from official documentation on https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html?highlight=data_files#keywords)

Comment: @Stephan Hmm, whoops, I haven't used it for a long while and didn't notice the deprecation. I'm confused about your claim that it won't work with wheels though, it does still work with a .whl file distribution, even with using the latest versions of pip/setuptools/wheel. I've put an example wheel on test.pypi.org [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/scripts-for-stephan/0.1/#files) which was created with the construct shown in this answer, you can install it with `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ scripts-for-stephan==0.1`.

Comment: Looking at the discussion [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/should-there-be-a-new-standard-for-installing-arbitrary-data-files/7853) it seems the setuptools documentation is misleading, and that it does still pass `data_files` values to wheel _provided they are relative paths_ (so that they can be installed relative to `sys.prefix` in e.g. a virtualenv). Absolute paths do not work, but you don't need that.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot for all your additional work @wim. I'll re-accept the answer as solution.